# Jupyter nbconvert: extend reveal.js ; add style and script in header

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

As the title suggests: I'd like to extend the *reveal* template of jupyter's nbconvert and add some custom `<style type="text/css"> ... </style>` and `<script> ... </script>` blocks right before the end of the `</head>`.

I'm currently using Linux and anaconda3 with `jupyter 4.7` and `nbconvert 6.0.7` .

I created a folder called *reveal_extension* in `~/anaconda3/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/` with the files:

- conf.json
- base.html.j2

**conf.json** is a copy of the *conf.json* file of the *reveal* template, with `"base_template": "reveal",`

**base.html.j2** is a new file with the following content:

```
{%- extends 'reveal/base.html.j2' -%}

{%- block html_head -%}

{{ super() }}

<style type="text/css">
  CSS-code
</style>

<script>
 javascript-code
</script>


{%- endblock html_head -%}
```

When I compile my *jupyter.ipynb* notebook with this template, I get a valid output with *reveal.js* but without my additional code.
`jupyter nbconvert jupyter.ipynb --to slides --template=reveal_extension`

When I manually add the code in the output *jupyter.slides.html* file, everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

How can I insert additional code in the *reveal.js* presentation with *nbconvert* using a template?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: no, unfortunately not... I'm altering the results with an external script now

Answer (score 2):

I think that you mixed up the Jinja templates. According to the [`nbconvert docs`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html#inheritance-in-jinja), `index.html.j2` is the main entry point.

If I take approximately your `base.html.j2` file and

1. rename it to `index.html.j2`
2. replace `{%- extends 'reveal/base.html.j2' -%}` by `{%- extends 'reveal/index.html.j2' -%}`

I get the added code in the converted HTML.